# help on manipulating this algebraic expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, induction, factorial

So I have something like:

$\frac {k!}{(k-3)!3!}$

I'm going to add $\frac 12k(k-1)$ to this, and I want to obtain $\frac {(k+1)!}{(k-2)!3!}$ as the result. I'm having trouble with this since I need a $k+1$ in the numerator and a $k-2$ in the denominator. Any hints please? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm going to do $\frac 1 2 k (k - 1)$ to this"?

Comment: Do you want to obtain $\frac{(k+1)!}{(k-2)!3!}$ from the original expression?

Comment: I meant I wanted to add, sorry about that typo

Comment: Note that what you add is $$\frac{k!}{(k-2)!2!}.$$ Find the common denominator, add.

Comment: ^ That worked, that was a really smart way to think of it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac {k!}{(k-3)!3!}=\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)}{6(k-3)}=\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{6}$ 
$\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)}{6(k-3)}=\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{6}$ 
$\frac {k!}{(k-3)!3!}+\frac{1}{2}k(k-1)=\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{6}+\frac{1}{2}k(k-1)=\frac{k(k+1)(k-1)}{6}=\frac{(k+1)!}{3!}$.

On the other hand $\frac {(k+1)!}{(k-2)!3!}=\frac {(k+1)k(k-1)(k-2)!}{(k-2)!3!}=\frac{(k+1)!}{3!}$. So they are equal.